# How to combine projections with transform in C++20 ranges

Tags: c++, c++20, std-ranges

C++20 `ranges::sort` supports projections, and that is great, but I want to do stuff that is more complex, in particular sort on result of function that operates on projected member.

For function call I tried the transform and then sort that view, but C++20 sort seems to not work on views, this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60338142/700825) explains why(for range-v3).

In other words can I write [this](https://godbolt.org/z/3c967K1Ya) without using a lambda/functor?

```
struct S{
    int val;
};

int origin = 47;

// assume we can not change Distance to take S
int Distance(int val){
    return std::abs(val - origin);
}

void my_sort(std::vector<S> ss) {
  std::ranges::sort(ss, std::greater<>{}, [](const S& s){
      return Distance(s.val);
  });
}
```

Comment: What's wrong with lambda? You can create a function to have something like `Chained(&S::val, &Distance)`...

Comment: One other way is to implement `bool operator < (const S& ss) const` in struct and use `std::sort`

Comment: @Jarod42 nothing in particular, I just prefer to not write lambdas if I dont have to, for example I really love projections since they allow me to do a lot of stuff that required lambdas before.

Comment: Something like [`compose`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/master/libs/hof/doc/html/include/boost/hof/compose.html) from boost::hof?

Comment: @Caleth yes, that is in the accepted answer, nice suggestion

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems like you want function composition:

```cpp
void my_sort(std::vector<S>& ss) {
  std::ranges::sort(ss, std::greater<>{}, compose(Distance, &S::val));
}
```

Where `compose(f, g)(x)` does `f(g(x))`. Boost.Hof has a [`compose`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/master/libs/hof/doc/html/include/boost/hof/compose.html), there's one in range-v3 somewhere too. Not one in the standard library though.

---

> For function call I tried the transform and then sort that view,

There is a big difference between `sort(r, less(), f)` and `sort(r | transform(f), less())`: the former sorts `r` using the function `f` as the sort key, the latter sorts the *transformed values specifically*. A concrete example demonstrating the difference:

```cpp
struct X {
    int i;
    int j;
};

vector<X> xs = {X{1, 2}, X{2, 1}, X{0, 7}};

// this would give you (0, 7), (1, 2), (2, 1)
// because we're sorting by the i
ranges::sort(xs, less(), &X::i);

// this would have given you (0, 2), (1, 1), (2, 7)
// because we're sorting the i's independently
ranges::sort(xs | views::transform(&X::i), less());
```

Comment: Unintiutive but it makes sense, I thought that "transformed" items are still seen as one object since there is .base in view iterators... but I guess when I think about it this also makes sense. :) 
I presume there is no way to ask politely std::ranges::sort to "sort entire objects"(use .base())

Comment: @NoSenseEtAl I disagree that it's unintuitive. `sort` sorts the thing you give it. If the thing you give it is the `i` members, it'll sort the `i` members. If you want to sort the whole `X`, then you ask it to sort the `X`s. It's also the difference between the largest value by key -- `ranges::max(f, less(), key)` -- and the largest key -- `ranges::max(f | transform(key))`.

Comment: @NoSenseEtAl Also if your transformation returns prvalues, they don't have an address to be swapped. A projection returning prvalues is fine, because that is immediately consumed by the comparison

Comment: @Barry now that I think about it you are right, I guess I based my expectation on old std::sort that never worked on transform_view.

Comment: @Caleth good point,  was just thinking how to do projection and I thought of transform_view but it is obviously very different thing...

Comment: ...or, if you are using an implementation that doesn't implement LWG3520, then the `views::transform` version can arbitrarily permute the remaining parts.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `views::transform` if your `S` has only one member:

```
void my_sort(std::vector<S> ss) {
  std::ranges::sort(
    ss | std::views::transform(&S::val), std::ranges::greater{}, Distance
  );
}
```

[Demo.](https://godbolt.org/z/5bzh5v15T)

Comment: weird, I could swear I tried views::transform and sort failed... ,let me try to recreate that

Comment: I was transforming with Distance, that did not work. https://godbolt.org/z/4Ejcxhnnz Not sure why your example works, mine does not.

Comment: This swaps the `int`s of `S`. If it has other data members, they get left behind

Comment: @Caleth. So I said "*if your S has only one member*".

Comment: if your S has only one member and its copyable?